# Blender Graphics Issue?

Tags: interface

[image: IdkWhatToPutHere]

So, recently I'd updated windows and I now have this issue with blender, shown above. This graphics issue can be created by scrolling in, pulling the points around and changing views. What is causing this? Has windows somehow tampered with files required for blender to work fluently? And what are said resolutions for the problem?

Comment: update the drivers for your GPU

Comment: i have updated the GPU drivers, restarted my PC as a result and the problem has remained. could you suggest anything else?